# Is there an API for subscribing to all updates to all data blocks?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I'm trying to write a package for Emacs which lets you view Blender's state in plain text with streaming updates.  To do so, I'd like to be able to get a stream of updates for when data blocks are added or modified. I found the [`depsgraph_update_post`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.handlers.html#bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post) handler, but that doesn't seem to fire on every change.  E.g. changing the Properties tab's context from Physics to Object doesn't seem to trigger `depsgraph_update_post`.

I see that there's an [`update`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#update-example) callback that you can register for any property, but it seems inefficient and clunky to have to register for each property in each data block.  Also, it seems like the `update` argument is not available for all property types (e.g [`CollectionProperty`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#bpy.props.CollectionProperty)), so it seems that you wouldn't be able to listen for new data blocks.

Comment: What does changing Properties Editor tabs have to do with updates to any data blocks?

Comment: I think this is something you want to do plugging directly into the source code, not all interactions with Blender systems are available to the python API.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys I'm probably using the wrong terminology.  I'm referring to whatever data structures eventually get serialized and saved to disk.  Since the Properties Editor tab's context is persistent between restarts, I assumed it was saved in the blend file, but now I realize that's perhaps a mistaken assumption; it might be saved elsewhere.

Comment: Actually you are right. That info is saved with the file in some data block.